# Node.JS update-JSON Formatting

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Im working with a module known as update-json. Im attempting to update json within a file, im having issues addressing the key I want or what seems to happen is a new entry gets added in a different branch..

My Querykeys.json looks like this

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "netdomain": "google.com",
      "netshare": "password",
      "authip": "216.58.203.46"
    },
    {
      "netdomain": "localhost",
      "netshare": "localghost",
      "authip": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    {
      "netdomain": "facebook.com",
      "netshare": "timeline",
      "authip": "31.13.69.228"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently I have the system reading and isolating code just fine, my intenetions are to update a netshare from the code of localhost from localghost to "foo".

The module in question is located here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/update-json.

The code i have setup is exactly like there code is on the website.

```
var updateJson = require('update-json');

// let's assume the file contains this: 
// {aaa: 'bbb', ccc: 'ddd'} 
var file_path = './querykeys.json';

var data = {servers: 'xxx', yyy: 'zzz'};

updateJson(file_path, data, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  else {
    console.log();
  }
});
```

With the type of structure that I have, how can i format `var data` to independently change localhosts netshare to `foo`?

Thank you

Comment: Looking over [update-json code](https://github.com/fczbkk/update-json/blob/master/lib/index.js#L21), it only seems to enable updating top-level keys in the JSON. You'd be better off rolling your own read/update/write code.

Comment: you have to -> load the file -> parse -> changeData -> stringify -> save